If you end a run of optionals with " ?? null", will you end with either the value, or a null (i.e., avoiding an undefined)?
Say you have a very large object, such as:
const cc = stuff.galaxies[13].stars[2099].planets["Jingo"].cities

I've mixed both arrays and objects.
Of course, something could be absent along the way.
I tend to do this:
const cc = stuff.galaxies?[13]?.stars?[2099]?
               .planets?["Jingo"]?.cities ?? null
if (cc === null) {
    // something was missing in the json at one of
    // galaxies, the 13th index of galaxies,
    // stars, the 2099th index of stars,
    // planets dictionary, or the "Jingo" item of planets,
    // or the cities entry (whether that is an array or object)
}

This does seem to work, it would result in cc being the array of cities, or null (no undefined).
Or another example might be
const j = stuff.galaxies?[13]?.stars?[2099]?.planets?["Jingo"] ?? null
if (cc === null) {
    // something was missing in the json at one of
    // galaxies, the 13th index of galaxies,
    // stars, the 2099th index of stars,
    // or planets dictionary, or the "Jingo" item of planets
}

Is this correct?

Yes, because undefined ?? null = null.

This is the correct format for optional chaining:
const cc = stuff?.galaxies?.[13]?.stars?.[2099]?.planets?.["Jingo"]?.cities ?? null;

The nullish coalescing operator (??) ensures that if the left-hand side evaluates to null or undefined, the right-hand side (in your case, null) is returned instead.
Note: only null or undefined, not 0 or false or other non-truthy values. This is different from the OR operator (||), which is satisfied by any non-truthy value (null, undefined, 0, false, ...)
Re: the ?? null in your example. With optional chaining you will receive undefined if some part of the chain fails. If you added the null coalescing in order to "catch" failed chains it isn't necessary (unless you specifically want null to be the result).

That is great information SandroPasquall thanks.  indeed I find it more sensible to ensure that NULL is the only possible failure response.  Checking for null is quite simple and rational , === NULL and that's the end of it.

I edited in to the question, my understanding of what it means if the expression results in null. TY !
